# Render or redirect content from different controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, render

im new to rails so this is a beginner question. I want to make an admin page for an app with views from different controllers
I tried

```
render 'projects/index'
```

and it throws

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
```

also didnt have much luck with redirect_to (no routes match)

what is the best technique for doing that? I have a feeling it must be super simple and I'm missing something

Comment: Render is the correct method. We'll need to see the stack trace and the view code to help out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nil error that you're getting looks like a problem with the view.  Your view may be using an array that wasn't initialized in your controller.  Every controller rendering your admin view must initialize the arrays being used in your view.

That said, it sounds like your view should be rendered from only one controller.

Comment: Your error says "The error occurred while evaluating nil.each".  This means that you view probably contains a statement like: "@variable.each" but @variable wasn't set in the controller

I'll be able to help more if you post the code from your view and controller.

Comment: ok I figured out how to define the array, but now it's complaining about missing partial admin/stub (which resides in the original projects view). If I duplicate the stub in admin folder it complains about other nil arrays. Is there a simpler way to do it without duplicating the files across the folders?

Comment: It's a good idea to follow the programming principle of Don't Repeat Yourself (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself).  Basically, for various reasons, you shouldn't have duplicate code in your application.
For your case, it sounds like you need to create one view for your admin page.  You can then "render" that page from multiple controllers.  (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Comment: These are important concepts for Rails and MVC programming in general.  A good rails tutorial should help you get a solid understanding of these concepts.  This is a great free tutorial: http://ruby.railstutorial.org.